# Growing Fractal Tree on Mouse Click

Tags: java, tree, jbutton, graphics2d, fractals

How can I make the fractal tree grow on each press of a JButton? I wanted to make it look like it is branching out more each time a button is clicked.

I currently have this code that draws the fractal tree.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class Tree {
    public float posX = 0;
    public float posY = 0;

    public void Tree(){

    }

    public void branch(Graphics2D g2, float len) {
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));

        g2.draw(new Line2D.Float(posX, posY, 0, -len)); // Draw the branch itself

        g2.translate(0, -len); // Move to the end of that line

        len *= 0.66; // Shrink the length of the branch

        if (len > 2) { // Base case: exit when the length of the branch is 2
                        // pixels or less
            AffineTransform at = g2.getTransform();
            g2.rotate(Math.PI / 5); // Rotate to the right
            branch(g2, len); // Call itself to draw two shorter branches
            g2.setTransform(at);

            // Repeat the same thing
            at = g2.getTransform();
            g2.rotate(-Math.PI / 5);
            branch(g2, len);
            g2.setTransform(at);
        }
    }
}
```

and I also have a Panel Class which displays the tree in the garden setting (garden class not included)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;



public class Panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener  {

    public static final int WINDOW_W = 1280;
    public static final int WINDOW_H = 720;

    private JButton simpleGarden;

    private Text txt;
    Tree tree;

    Garden garden;

    public Panel(){
        this.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WINDOW_W, WINDOW_H));
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        simpleGarden = new JButton("START YOUR GARDEN");
        add(simpleGarden);
        simpleGarden.addActionListener(this);

        txt = new Text();

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        if (garden != null){
            garden.showGarden(g2);
            g2.setColor(new Color(139,69,19));
            g2.translate(WINDOW_W/2, WINDOW_H - 75);
            tree.branch(g2, 120); // display fractal
            txt.removeText(g2);
            }
        else{
            txt.startGarden(g2);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getActionCommand() == "START YOUR GARDEN") {
            garden = new SimpleGarden();
            tree = new Tree();

            remove(simpleGarden);
        }



        repaint();

    }

}
```

Comment: Devise a virtual view of your fractal, which can be updated via a simple method call.  Each time you click the button, you update this virtual view.  You then have your `Panel` repaint and paint the entire virtual tree based on it's current state

Comment: Thanks! I'm really new at this so I hope you can clarify more things. So what I did was I created a "Grow Tree" Jbutton in Panel and a grow() method in Tree class to update the fractal. The actionPerformed method calls this grow() method when "Grow Tee" is pressed. Right now I have tree.branch(g2, 120); to paint the fractal. What do I put in the grow() method?

Comment: The problem is, painting is destructive.  Each time a paint cycle occurs, you are expected to wipe your output clean and repaint it from scratch.  Because a paint cycle may occur at any time for any number of reasons, you need some way to know what should be painted in an independent way, hence this idea that you build a virtual fractal, which carries with it the information that would be required to paint it.

Comment: How do I create this virtual fractal? I only know the paint method

Comment: I'd recommend taking the time to do some research into btrees